# How to change a column type in GoogleBigQuery from String to Record

Tags: casting, google-bigquery

I have an export defined from StackDriver to BigQuery, and because the column type are auto detected one of my columns are set to be a STRING (becuase at first it was empty).

When I try to write a RECORD into it, I get the following error:

```
Error details: Field jsonpayload.params.amount: This field is not a record.
```

I tried to cast it from STRING to RECORD in several ways:

1.By running a Cast method in BigQuery SQL:

```
SELECT 
*, CAST(jsonPayload.params.amount AS RECORD) AS `jsonPayload.params.amount`
FROM `development.xxx.
```

2. Tried to export the data and import it and specify the exact type

But I failed in both.
How can I change the type of an existing column?

Comment: you can't just define a record, you need to specify the contents of the record - do you have more info about that?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [STRUCT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#declaring-a-struct-type).